Datatable2 - RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded
I am trying to insert Datatable2 inside my Scaffold but I am getting this error:
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded

I changed expanded to widget, I covered singlechildscrollview inside container but still same error.
Here is my main widget.
Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,

          body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[

                Flexible(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<Article>>(
                    future: fetchpostsfuture,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

                      posts = snapshot.data;
                      return snapshot.hasData
                          ? (snapshot.data?.length == 0
                          ? Center(
                        child: Text('Nothing Found',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      )
                          :  Container(
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child:  DataTable2(
                            fixedTopRows: 1,
                            fixedLeftColumns: 1,
                            columns: [...],
                            rows: [...],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                          : SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0);
                    },
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )

How can I solve this problem?
